# not able to print values of object using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

This is my html code :

```html
<h3 ng-repeat="goal in goals" ng-controller="AddGoalsCtrl"> 
    <h4 ng-repeat="(key,value) in goal" ng-controller="AddGoalsCtrl">
        {{key}} : {{value}}
    </h4>
</h3>
```

and this is what my service layer returns :

```
[Goal [goalId=1, goalName=goal1, goalDescription=goaldescript, measurementCriteria=crtr, visible=Y], Goal [goalId=2, goalName=goal1, goalDescription=goal 1 description, measurementCriteria=criteria1, visible=Y], Goal [goalId=3, goalName=goal1, goalDescription=goal 1 description, measurementCriteria=criteria1, visible=Y]]
```

or json as :

```
[{"goalId":1,"goalName":"goal1","goalDescription":"goaldescript","measurementCriteria":"crtr","visible":"Y"},{"goalId":2,"goalName":"goal1","goalDescription":"goal 1 description","measurementCriteria":"criteria1","visible":"Y"},{"goalId":3,"goalName":"goal1","goalDescription":"goal 1 description","measurementCriteria":"criteria1","visible":"Y"}]
```

but my html is not printing anything like key:value .......

Comment: this is html ng-repeat loop
"<h3 ng-repeat="goal in goals" ng-controller="AddGoalsCtrl"> 

 <h4 ng-repeat="(key,value) in goal" ng-controller="AddGoalsCtrl">
  {{key}} : {{value}}
 </h4>
 
</h3>"

Comment: don't add ng-controller to the tag that has ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are loading controller many times in a partial.it should not be like that.html code should like this:

```
<div ng-controller="AddGoalsCtrl">
    <h3 ng-repeat="goal in goals" > 
        <h4 ng-repeat="(key,value) in goal">
        {{key}} : {{value}}
        </h4>
   </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a plunker for you at http://plnkr.co/twdDzpxikJMTe0WuN7ro.

You shouldn't be nesting the controller try something like the following instead:

```
<body ng-controller="AddGoalsCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="goal in goals">
        <h4 ng-repeat="(key,value) in goal">
            {{key}} : {{value}}
        </h4>
    </div> 
</body>
```

Also, don't nest an h tag within another it's not symantically correct HTML. I used a div instead for the outer repeat since you weren't doing anything with it in this example.

Comment: Hi, I am still not getting values printed.......
this is my service layer code :
'@RequestMapping(value = "getGoalList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody List<Goal> getGoalList() {
  logger.info(" Inside getGoalList");
  List<Goal> goals = goalDao.getGoalList();
  System.out.println("back in controller with list of goals !!");
  System.out.println(goals);
  return goals;
 }'

Comment: and in console log for 'System.out.println(goals);' I get output as **[Goal [goalId=1, goalName=goal1, goalDescription=goaldescript, measurementCriteria=crtr, visible=Y], Goal [goalId=2, goalName=goal1, goalDescription=goal 1 description, measurementCriteria=criteria1, visible=Y], Goal [goalId=3, goalName=goal1, goalDescription=goal 1 description, measurementCriteria=criteria1, visible=Y]]
**